# NFA for regular expression (ab)*(ba)* U aa*

Tags: regex, computation-theory, nfa

I am studying NFA and this one troubled me a bit so I'd like to ask, am I right on making this? (Sorry, I am really bad at paint...)
[image]

Comment: What do you feel might be wrong?

Comment: I have a feeling it is correct but not so sure :D

Comment: @darkchampionz Your NFA is not correct, it actually accepts `abbaab`

Comment: You are right... Uploaded a new image.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the NDFA of your expression:

[image]